# Remove post author using child theme

Tags: author, child-theme, theme-twenty-twelve

I'm using twentytwelve but I don't want the author to show on single post pages. How would I go about doing that without deleting it from the parent theme.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you are using a child theme based on Twenty Twelve. That being the case, you would just include the appropriate file or files in your child theme.

Your child theme could include a [`single.php` file](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/single.php) edited to do what you want, but you probably don't have to. That file calls `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );` to display the content, which will load [one of these](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve):

- comments.php
- content-aside.php
- content-image.php
- content-link.php
- content-none.php
- content-page.php
- content-quote.php
- content-status.php
- content.php

Your child theme can include one or more of those files edited to be missing the author data.

Nothing gets removed from the parent. The files just get substituted.

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes